# Genes mirror geography on a torus?

Tags: dg.differential-geometry, random-matrices, mathematical-biology

Disclaimer: this is an open-ended, imprecise question, asking for speculation in a topic that I know relatively little about (random matrix theory and principal component analysis). I originally [asked it on MSE](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3653984/genes-mirror-geography-on-a-torus) and have copied it over here. I wanted to air this curiosity, but if it is not appropriate for MO, flag it and let me know.

Two years ago, I participated in a directed reading group on the Marchenko-Pastur law, led by one of my favorite professors ever, Brent Nelson. To motivate the subject, he showed us a [paper](https://www.nature.com/articles/nature07331) entitled "Genes Mirror Geography Within Europe." Since there is a paywall, I will briefly summarize this motivating result.

The researchers compiled genetic data from a group of Europeans, ensuring (whenever possible) that each person's grandparents were of the same nationality, so that an individual country of origin could reasonably be assigned. These genetic markers were compiled into a matrix $X$. Random matrix theory predicts a spectrum that the eigenvalues of $X^T\!X$ should closely fit to, if the genetic data were indeed random. However, two main outliers appeared, representing signals among the random noise. The eigenvectors corresponding to these eigenvalues gave two data points on each individual. When this data was plotted (color-coding individuals by their country of origin), the resulting scatter plot had a remarkable resemblance to a map of Europe (color-coded by country). I believe that the scale of the axes was adjusted to show this resemblance, but their angle was not (i.e. the eigenvectors represent orthogonal geographical directions). They say that this outcome "fits the theoretical expectation for models in which genetic similarity decays with distance in a two-dimensional habitat, as opposed to expectations for models involving discrete well-differentiated populations." They also note that the much larger outlying eigenvalue corresponds to a NNW direction, indicating that genetic variation is more strongly correlated with latitude than longitude (this makes sense to me, since the former has much more to do with climate).

Now Europe covers a small portion of the Earth's surface, so this may as well be happening on a plane instead of a sphere. There are several good reasons for this: most of the Earth's surface is water, where human's do not often reside; probably, more genetic and family-historical data is available to the researchers for Europeans than for other groups; and projects of colonialism, imperialism and enslavement have had their impact on geography, genetics and family history of people in many other parts of the world. But I am curious about what would happen if a similar analysis were performed on a population occupying a topologically different region.

From the researchers' quote about theoretical models, it seems reasonable that letting "genetic similarity [decay] with distance in [an $r$-dimensional] habitat" should produce $r$ principal components. In fact, I would be completely unsurprised if this were already common knowledge, which was just unknown to me. But the output (vectors of data-points) is inherently Euclidean, so I wonder what would happen if the populations were no longer simply evolving in a portion of Euclidean space. For example, if a species populated the entire surface of a planet, how would the geography of the spheroid be reflected in the principal component analysis? What about on a torus? Would there still be 2 principal components corresponding to the 2 dimensions of the surface, or would there be more? If there were 2 principal components, how would points of the surface be identified under this map? More broadly, since distance certainly plays a role, how would the Riemannian geometry of a surface be reflected in the data?

I would be interested to hear any guesses or speculation from those with a better understanding of principal component analysis or genetic variations than myself.

Comment: Not on a torus, but related: scientists have investigated the existence of "ring species" https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ring_species
where genetic distance (at least as measured by ability of individuals to breed) does not reflect geometry/topology.

Comment: Thank you, that's interesting! So, to put this into topological terms, this gives a phenomenon that prompts speciation to occur more frequently on a non-simply connected region?